# Access aws s3 bucket to stage file for mapbox tileset

Tags: amazon-s3, mapbox

I have a mapbox tileset that I want to add data to. So I installed curl and aws cli version 2 and I tried to run this command on from a Linux (WSL) terminal:

```
curl -X POST https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/username/credentials?access_token=<secret access token>
```

That command is taken from the [mapbox docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/upload-curl/). But I get the following response:

```
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

This isn't much feedback to work with. How can I get the needed aws credentials? Is it that I need an aws account or something? In the curl command above I inserted my username and access_token, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure that your access token is a secret access token with

```
uploads:write
```

scope enabled?

This can be done when creating the secret token from within your Mapbox access tokens page:
https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your username and password are correct, and make sure you're not putting it in quotes.

curl -X POST https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/rawstringusername/credentials?access_token=rawstringtoken

Other than that, make sure you're not behind a VPN